# gcc warning for redundant assignment

Tags: c, gcc

Assuming I have a code like:

```
int foo(int a) {
   int b;
   b = 0;
   b = a+1;
   return b;
}
```

The assignment `b=0` is obviously redundant and not needed. Can `gcc` catch such errors?

I know it would be optimized out, but I also want to see a warning (and clean it up).

I thought the `-Wunused-value` should work with it, but small testing (with `gcc version 11`) proved me wrong. So which option of `gcc` can help?

Comment: A good IDE like CLion will detect this.

Comment: It's not an unused variable because you eventually use in `return b;`

Comment: According to [Bug 77430 - warn about redundant assignments](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77430), such assignments should be catched by Clang.

Comment: In general, gcc is not big on giving "dead code" warnings, so I'm not too surprised that there doesn't seem to be any way to detect this.  I'm not sure if that's a deliberate decision that such a feature is not useful, or if the design of the compiler makes it difficult to provide them.